# CSS Padding in TheGem Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

Hi is there anyone that can help me? It seems no one, not even the WP Bluehost people can figure this out and I so need to complete this part to move on or start completely over. The site is [www.myvinti.com](http://www.myvinti.com) (temp domain). I added Rev Sliders to the one page block site, but this even happens on other sites I work on, and there is this padding I was told with visual composer that I can not remove. It is a colored padding and for some reason I cannot even find it in the CSS to update. The people from Rev Slider stated it is something that VC did and I have to contact them but the VC came with this theme so I can't get any help and the coders won't respond.

I wanted to add multiple sliders but can't do that as well. [Inspector Image from Rev Slider Techs to reflect issue- please view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJvqT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the custom css field on the page:

```
.vc_custom_1489705836592 .vc_column-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I am not sure WHY in the world these so called WP experts you pay to help you through WP couldn't figure this out and it has been weeks yet you were able to instantly!

Comment: Can you please tell me where I find this code??? I am switching theme pages and used my slider on a new home page and it is showing again. www.myvinti.com/agency-light. Please I have tried all day to find it under inspect element and I think the 1489... # changes for each page?